how does the rust borrow checker behave with pointer
How does the borrow checker behave when workin with pointers? Will the borrow checker not work at all or will this cause a problem? My guess is that when dropping a ref from a pointer nothing will happen.
Im just starting with unsafe rust & want to make sure not to cause any memory leaks or undefined behavior
let ptr = Box::into_raw(Box::new(value));
let a = unsafe { &*ptr };
let b = unsafe { &*ptr };
drop(a);
drop(b);


It's not clear, what is expected when dropping a and b. They are references, so dropping them will not drop the referenced value. Were you attempting to cause a double-free?

A pointer is not dropped or freed. Pointers will cause memory leaks if you don't de-allocate the underlying value manually, or convert it back to a type that Rust will deallocate for you

yeah I know that. In safe rust you can't have more than one reference to a variable. let data ="".to_string(); let a = &data; let b = &data; would not work. That's why I asked how the borrow checker would behave since a&b are in save code now.

@DerFrederikHD you can have as many immutable/shared references as you like; that code compiles just fine. Perhaps you are confusing it with mutable/exclusive references; for instance this doesn't compile.

The code you wrote will not drop anything since you are only dropping references. Dropping a reference is basically a no-op in Rust. You also violate rust's rules by creating references to an invalid value. Changing it slightly will result a Double Free too (even a triple free since the original box was dropped before the unsafe code).
let ptr = Box::into_raw(Box::new(value));
let a = unsafe { Box::from_raw(ptr) };
let b = unsafe { Box::from_raw(ptr) };
drop(a);
drop(b);

Unsafe code is telling rust to let you handle the safety. The requirements are stricter than C despite it feeing like the same level of freedom. Since you mentioned this is the start of your unsafe journey here are some helpful resources:

The Rustonomicon: Incomplete but helpful general reference
Miri: A great tester for catching issues with unsafe code. Runs a ton slower than normal execution
Pinning: You really need to understand this if you're messing with async unsafe

Also good to understand async better, I think everyone should know this
I had to write my own async executor before I really got it though
More good reading
Understanding this also leads to self referential structs, if you go that far remember drop order matters


Send and Sync: Needed for going into multithreading

The best way to learn this better is to avoid Mutexs wherever possible (You should almost never need them with some fancy data structures/threading layouts)
Atomics are really fast. A common narrative is that they're slow but they are many orders of magnitude faster than Mutexs. Also are constant-ish time (unless you do a CAS loop)




The requirements are not strictly stricter than C. There are some rules in Rust not in C (mainly mutable aliasing) and some in C but not in Rust (the biggest being probably Type Based Alias Analysis).

@ChayimFriedman I'm not familiar with Type Based Alias Analysis but from what I see on a search it has to do with pointer/variable aliasing. When it comes to writing rust code I believe it has a stronger requirement since Rust requires all mutable references to be aliased vs in C you can write code that aliases through a pointer that can mutate. Would love to know more about what I'm missing.

It is not strictly stricter, as I said. One can argue Rust's aliasing rules are stricter, but they are not strictly so - they allow things TBAA disallows.
